# ngx-datatable in angular2 filter back results on backspace

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable (http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#filter) in my angular project and trying to add a filter. The filter is added successfully on the column specified, however when I erase the filter characters with backspace, my original list data is not populated back.

My HTML:

```
<input
    type='text'
    style='padding:8px;margin:15px auto;width:30%;'
    placeholder='Type to filter the task name column...'
    (keyup)='updateFilter($event)'
  />
<div>
    <ngx-datatable  class="material"
    [rows]="tasks"
    [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

and in my component I have:

```
rows = [];
columns = [
{ name: 'Id' },
{ name: 'What task', prop: 'what_task' },
{ name: 'Budget', prop:'tentative_budget' }
];

temp = [];
ngOnInit() {

    this.taskListService.getTasks().subscribe(
        tasks => {
            console.log(tasks);
            this.tasks=tasks;
            this.tableData=this.tasks;
            this.tableModel.addAll(this.tableData);

        }
        )
}

updateFilter(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    // filter our data
    const temp = this.tasks.filter(function(d) {
        console.log(d.what_task.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val)
        return d.what_task.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });

    // update the rows
    this.tasks = temp;

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple logical mistake. Try something like this

HTML

```
<ngx-datatable  class="material"
[rows]="tableData"
[columns]="columns">
```

TS

```
updateFilter(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

// filter our data
const temp = this.tasks.filter(function(d) {
    console.log(d.what_task.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val)
    return d.what_task.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
});

// update the rows
this.tableData= temp;

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked, what should be the type of tableData though? I am asking because I had it used but that was from angular2-mdl table I used which had type IMdlTableModelItem

Comment: I assume you get tasks as a JSON. So you can make a simple model class and us it as a type. You can parse json to TS class using something like this  http://json2ts.com/